# Bulk insertion using single or optimized query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate 3.

My question is, how to optimize multiple insert queries or fire multiple queries using single insert query using Hibernate or HQL.

I've already gone through the following links:

[how to make HQL that will generate SQL to insert multiple values in one statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862180/how-to-make-hql-that-will-generate-sql-to-insert-multiple-values-in-one-statemen)

[HQL Bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751135/hql-bulk-insert)

And I've found that my question slightly varies. My queries are:

```
INSERT INTO scoring.table_a (a_id, a_name) VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO scoring.table_a (a_id, a_name) VALUES (2, 'b');
....
...
..
INSERT INTO scoring.table_a (a_id, a_name) VALUES (1000, 'd');
```

The set of values are different for multiple columns & not for the single column. Also the values being entered are calculated & not taken directly from some table. So `INSERT INTO... SELECT` also, I might not able to use. Because as per my knowledge, `INSERT INTO... SELECT` fetches data from another table.

I've also read about batch processing, but that too fires multiple insert queries, which I don't want to use.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Do you know this `INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3`

Comment: @RabNawaz Thanks for quick reply. I didn't know about this query. But after your suggestion, I searched on net & found that, this query is plain SQL. Can you tell me how can I convert it into HQL?

Answer (score 0):

What I could suggest you here to use a hibernate entity like

```
@Entity(name = table_a)
public class TableAEntity{

@id
@Column(name="a_id")
String aId;

@Column(name = "a_name")
String aName;

public TableAEntity(String aId, String aName){
  this.aId=aid;
  this.aName =aName;
}

// Getter setter for column aId, aName
}
```

Then you could something like update in a go, example taken from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-update%20%5B%20BatchUpdate%5D)

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    TableAEntity entity= new TableAEntity(.....);
    session.save(entity);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

More ways to do the same is given at the same link.

Comment: Will this fire one insert query or multiple insert queries?